# How to compare two serializer field and show whichever is higher in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `product serializer` which return `category_offer_price` & `product_offer_price`,
before getting this response I want to compare both price and only return whichever is highest price.

#Serilaizer.py

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    product_offer_price = SerializerMethodField()
    category_offer_price = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = [
            "id",
            "product_name",
            "slug",
            "category",
            "description",
            "category_offer_price",
            "product_offer_price",
            "base_price",
            "stock",
            "is_available",
            "created_date",
            "images",
            "images_two",
            "images_three",
        ]

    def get_product_offer_price(self, obj):
        try:
            product_offer = ProductOffer.objects.get(product=obj)
            if product_offer.is_active:
                offer_price = product_offer.product_offer_price()
                return offer_price
        except Exception:
            pass
        return None

    def get_category_offer_price(self, obj):
        try:
            category_offer = CategoryOffer.objects.get(category=obj.category)
            if category_offer.is_active:
                offer_price = category_offer.category_offer_price(obj)
                return offer_price
        except Exception:
            pass
        return None
```

#Models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    base_price = models.IntegerField()
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/products")
    images_two = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/products")
    images_three = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/products")
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

I'd like to know is it possible to compare serializer fields in a serializer class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move into one method, to validate your field. Also, substitute your try:except with [get-object-or-404 method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) and your serializer fields with [**all**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) value since you are using everything, to have a much cleaner code.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    price = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_price(self, obj):
        product_offer = get_object_or_404(ProductOffer, product=obj)
        category_offer = get_object_or_404(CategoryOffer, category=obj.category)

        if product_offer.is_active and category_offer.is_active:
            if product_offer.product_offer_price() > category_offer.category_offer_price(obj):
                    return product_offer.product_offer_price()
            else:
                    return category_offer.category_offer_price(obj)

        elif product_offer.is_active and not category_offer.is_active:
            return product_offer.product_offer_price()

        elif category_offer.is_active and not product_offer.is_active:
            return category_offer.category_offer_price(obj)
```

EDIT: As you can see I used the classic if/else in this solution, although since Python **3.10** you can use the [Match case statement](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-match-case-statement/) to substitute these conditions chain.

In case of objects do not exist:

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    price = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_price(self, obj):
        try:
            product_offer = ProductOffer.objects.filter(product=obj).first()
            category_offer = CategoryOffer.objects.filter(category=obj.category).first()
                
            if not product_offer and not category_offer:
                return obj.base_price            
            elif not category_offer:  
                return product_offer.product_offer_price()            
            elif not product_offer:
                return category_offer.category_offer_price(obj)                   
            elif category_offer and product_offer:
                if category_offer.is_active and not product_offer.is_active:
                    return category_offer.category_offer_price(obj)                
                elif product_offer.is_active and not category_offer.is_active:
                    return product_offer.product_offer_price()                
                elif category_offer.is_active and product_offer.is_active:
                    if category_offer.category_offer_price(obj) > product_offer.product_offer_price():
                        return category_offer.category_offer_price(obj)
                    else:
                        return product_offer.product_offer_price()
        except:
            return obj.base_price
```

Although, to be honest, if there could be no objects then the is_active field is redundant.

Comment: There is a problem in this, when there is no category offer, it will give you 404. I dont want that. I want to show normal listing even if there is no cathegroy or product offer assiigned

Comment: Yes, I assumed both offers would always exist. In that case what you want is to maintain the try:except and check if there are any objects inside the querysets, pior to checking the active status.

Comment: The updated one actually works except the category offer. when there is catgeory offer and any one of the product also has an offer,  then category offer wont work even if its higher

Comment: I've remade a complete test of the method and noticed that it was hitting an exception when one of the objects didn't exist. So , instead of get() method I used filter to get the first object of the QuerySet, now even if you have multiple offers, it should get your latest, even better if in your table you have a field to order_by().

Answer (score 2):

You can override `to_representation()`

Example:

```py
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    product_offer_price = SerializerMethodField()
    category_offer_price = SerializerMethodField()

    ...

    ...
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        # access required fields like this
        product_offer_price = data['product_offer_price']
        category_offer_price = data['category_offer_price']

        # do calculations here and returning the desired field as `calculated_price`
        if category_offer_price > product_offer_price:
            data['calculated_price'] = category_offer_price
        else:
            data['calculated_price'] = product_offer_price
        return data
```

Comment: @MahrusKhomaini also by this method you can also send only the field which is higher, without `calculated_price`

Comment: Noted. Sometimes I need it like this, and it's unthinkable to override the representation. Thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it s what you want but you could use a field of type SerializerMethodField which allow you to add a computed field that you could call category_offer_higher_price. Its value is computed by a function that return the highest one. See following link : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Hey i got it solved